# How do I login a user with Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I've added `accounts-password` and `useraccounts:unstyled`

I've included the signin template in my footer.html -

```
{{#if showSignIn}}
    {{> atForm state="signIn"}}
{{/if}}
```

I'm hard coding the creation of users as the app starts up -

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

if (!Acounts.findUserByEmail('aidan@gmail.com')) {
  Accounts.createUser({
    username: 'Aidan',
    email: 'aidan@gmail.com',
    password: 'securePassword'
  });
}
```

It's just that I can't work out how to actually log my user in. I've tried simply entering the password and email address into the form. That doesn't work (the form error says 'Login Forbidden').

I've tried adding the following line (to the same file as my account creation code) -

```
accountsServer.validateLoginAttempt(()=>{return true;});
```

Unsurprisingly that doesn't do anything.

I've tried add a submit event into my footer.js file -

```
Template.footer.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
    console.log('submitted');
    const email = document.getElementById('at-field-email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('at-field-password').value;
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);
  },
});
```

I can see that the event is firing, but when I try `Meteor.user()` in the console I still get `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's typo in `if (!Acounts.findUserByEmail('aidan@gmail.com'))` (it should have been `Accounts`). The user isn't being created.

To get a super simple functional login with a single hard coded user -

Add the accounts-password package and the ui user accounts package.

```
> meteor add accounts-password
> meteor add useraccouts:unstyled
```

The accounts-password package handles the actual logging in. The user accounts:unstyled packages provides a set of templates for accounts management.

Then add the login form to a template.

```
<template name="templateWithLogin">
    {{> atForm state="signIn"}}
</template>
```

Lastly create a user (e.g. in `/server/main.js`).

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

if (!Accounts.findUserByEmail('user@gmail.com')) {
  Accounts.createUser({
    username: 'User',
    email: 'user@gmail.com',
    password: 'securePassword'
  });
}
```

This should be **everything** needed to get a functional login form. There's loads of tutorials online for creating additional functionality. The main documentation is [here](http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#useraccounts).

Answer (score -1):

you can use {{>loginButtons}} to get the ui and {{#if currentUser }} for the functionality.